# show all warnings in IntelliJ

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

In my IntelliJ project, warnings/errors in the currently open file are shown with yellow/red markings in the ruler on the right-hand side of the editor. Is there anywhere I can easily see *all* errors warnings in the current project? The project is a Grails project, in case that makes any difference.

Answer (score 8):

Doesn't the inspector do that? You can create a custom inspector set via "Settings -> Errors -> Inspection profiles" for the yellow warnings.

You can can then run the inspection for all files and then use "group by severity" to separate the warnings and errors out.

No idea if this will work for groovy. It does work kind of like that for java.

Comment: You should also mention that he needs to go to the Analyze menu and run "Inspect code...". It's a little less convenient than Eclipse, where it has a window that simply shows every error and warning in the project.